# NASM AllocConsole, how set focus on it?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

These are the lines I use in NASM to allocate a new console, but when it opens, the focus isn't on it. Firstly I have to click on it to write or do some stuff.
Am I missing something?

```
call [AllocConsole] 
push dword title 
call [SetConsoleTitleA]
```

Comment: The fact that you're calling `AllocConsole` indicates that your application is a GUI application (otherwise you'd normally already have a console). Typically a console in a GUI application would be used for debug logs and things like that. Have you considered using a GUI element for user input instead? I suppose you could try calling `GetConsoleWindow` followed by `SetFocus`, but I'm not sure if that'll work.

Comment: Try calling [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539) with the console window handle.